# Running N functions vs 1 composed function

Tags: parallel-processing, functional-programming, composition

In the following video, [Thinking Parallel Programming](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Thinking-Parallel-Programming), in the end, Guy Steele recommends ways to improve your code performance

He mentions at around 1:01, if you have a state s and array of functions f[i], then rather than doing

```
for i <- 1 to n; s = f[i](s)
```

do

```
fcomposed(s) where fcomposed is the composition of all functions in f[i]
```

I don't see any benefit here. Have I misinterpreted something?

Comment: AFAICT, you are talking about a different abstraction level than he is. You (I think?) are thinking of the difference in code as you'd write it in an application. I think he is saying that, as the *compiler author*, one representation affords *him* more flexibility than the other. I may be off base, I didn't watch the entire thing yet.

Comment: even im talking about parallelism here. agreed that composing n functions can be parallilized. but once the big function runs, it'll take the same amount of time as running n functions afterall